# Header keeps ticking out of a div

Tags: html, css

I am in the process of creating a website. The website should have a bar at the top that is constantly visible. So far I have placed some buttons, an image and a headline inside the bar at the top. The bar at the top is made as a div and therefore I can't understand how my headline keeps ticking out below the bar at the top(div).

How do I make sure my headline stays inside my div and gets smaller as the page gets smaller?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tuhG.png)

Code shown below is for my bar (header-div), button and the header itself.

```
    `.Header-div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 7vh;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    z-index: 9999;
}

.Kalender, .Info {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 5%;
    height: 75%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 0.1%;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: 
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow:
}
.Header1 {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    
  }`
```

Comment: Please give the complete code. HTML + CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: you're specifying both `.Header-div` and `.Header` with `position: fixed`, so they're both [positioned relative to the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed).

Secondly: you're specifying a fixed height on the `.Header-div` which happens to be less than the height required to display its contents. The default rule is `overflow: visible`, which gives you the behaviour you see here.

If you remove the `position: fixed` rule for `.Header` and the `height` on `.Header-div`, then the height of `.Header-div` depends only on its contents.

This messes up your alignment on the inner div, but change `display: inline-flex` to `display: flex` and you're all good.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/se9n8Lxc/)

Answer (score 0):

As the motto's answer suggest, there are plenty of things to do with the given CSS. But responsive font size can also be achieved quite easilly itself by using [vw units](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_responsive_text) instead of `em` like you do. A `vw` stands for "viewport width", which is percentage of current browser window size.

For me it is super-easy and super-scalable, it only has a [few limitations](https://caniuse.com/viewport-units) related to some browsers.